# Integrating IM app with outlook 2013 not working without Lync installation

Tags: com, office-2013, outlook-2013, lync-2013

I have developed a local IM application (IM APP) with the help of article "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx", LyncSDk 2013, Lync basic 2013 & Outlook 2013.

It is working at development machine because environment is setup there.
When it is running with different machine, outlook 2013 is not responding to IM APP with functions GetAuthenticationInfo(), GetInterface() etc of interface UCOfficeIntegration.

When Lync 2013 got installed at same machine than outlook is working well with IM APP. I again uninstalled it then again Outlook stop to send the request to IM APP.
Microsoft.Office.UC.dll is part of office15 folder & registered with Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe.

I am not able to find out the issue & resolution. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you eventually figure how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This is an effect of COM. If you want that your IM App to work independent of Lync then you will have to register your type library in system. But for now till the date you don't have your on typelibrary you would need Lync to be installed.